# Windows store apps tapped event is very slow

Tags: events, performance, pressed

After running some performance tests on my new windows store app, I realized that all tapped-events are much slower than the pressed-events.

I have no idea why, but the problem is: I need it.

I can't use the pressed-event instead, because sometimes I need to implement a right-tapped event.

When doing a right-tap the (normal) tapped-event will be ignored. That's what I want.
Unfortunately the pressed-event will not be ignored, but always called.

So - what can I do now, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the tapped event is fired after pressed event. Because the Input system will wait until the pointer point is released in order to determine whether the action should be Tapped, Holding or some other getsture, so you could not get Tapped at the very instant that a user touches the screen.